# Implementing simple String Matching with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to implement simple regex string matching with wildcards in Java. So the idea is, you have a needle(the string to search for) and a haystack(the string being searched), you have to search for the needle in the haystack and give the starting index of the needle. The wildcard comes in in a situation where the string supplied as the needle is incomplete and the missing character(s) is/are replaced with an underscore '_'( for example test is equivalent to t_st or tes_t or te__). 
I have written a simple method that takes in the haystack and needle as arguments but I can't get it to work. I keep getting an IIllegalStateException: No match available error. Here is the code:

```
     static int findRegex(String needle, String haystack)
{
    char [] needleChars = needle.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

    builder.append(".*");
    for (char c: needleChars)
    {
        builder.append('(');
        builder.append(c);
        builder.append('|');            
        builder.append('_');
        builder.append(')');
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());

    return Pattern.compile(builder.toString()).matcher(haystack).start();
}
```

I have tested the regex pattern generated by the code (`.*(t|_)(e|_)(s|_)(t|_)`) and it works. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IIllegalStateException: No match available error` means, that regex engine wasn't able to find any match for your regex.

It can be thrown when

- you don't call one of these methods from your `Matcher` to let it search for match:

  - `matches()`
  - `find()`
  - `lookingAt()`
- result of these methods will be `false`, which means that despite trying, regex engine wasn't able to find any match. In that case there is no valid index which can be returned as `start()`.

Anyway I suspect that your method should look more like

```
static int findRegex(String needle, String haystack) {

    String regex = needle.replace("_", ".{0,10}?");
    //System.out.println(regex);

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(haystack);
    if (matcher.find()){
        return matcher.start();
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I simply replaced any `_` with with `.{0,10}?` to let it match any character (with limit to 10 characters). I also added `?` to make this quantifier reluctant so `te_t` would find minimal match.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much that works. Do you have any idea as to why I failed to get any match with the regex pattern I used?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: About `.*(t|_)(e|_)(s|_)(t|_)`: I am not really sure what this pattern was suppose to find since it can find zero or more characters which are ended with combination of letters like `t_s_`, `test`, `__st` or even `____`.